# Is there anyone familiar with Plurk API?

Tags: python

I try to fetch some data from Plurk using its "search" function.

[http://www.plurk.com/API#search](https://github.com/clsung/plurk-oauth)

I know I have to provide my app key and app secret, so I registered for my application.

But after I read official document:

http://www.plurk.com/API

and Python library it provides:

https://github.com/clsung/plurk-oauth

I still even didn't know how to start.

I've downloaded the library, but I'm not sure how to install it, and therefore don't know how to call the APIs.

Can someone teach me how to start calling Plurk API? (I want to search some things.)

Thanks! And I'm sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer by myself.
To setup the Plurk API, first you need "Python setuptool"(google it, and then download it)

afterwards, move to the directory where Plurk API placed under cmd mode, then type 'python setup.py'

notice that you need install Python 2.6+ to install the Python setuptool

and here is sample code to test if you install the Plurk API successfully:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from plurk_oauth.PlurkAPI import PlurkAPI

query = "beauty"

plurk = PlurkAPI('YOUR APP key', 'YOUR APP secret')
plurks = plurk.callAPI('/APP/PlurkSearch/search', {'query' : query})

for p in plurks["plurks"]:
  print p["content"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a [RESTful API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services), so you have to use `HTTP` methods to access the API. Check out [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html).